# SetInterval Iterations runtime increases

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, setinterval

I try to run my script forever in node.js, but I think something ist going wrong and I don't know what to do.
I run my script every one second:

```
async function main() {
  async function func() {
    var start_time = performance.now();
    for (let route of routes) {
      var result_amount = await calc(route);
      if (result_amount[5] > amount_start * 1.0) {
          //Do something
      }
    }
    var end_time = performance.now();
    var total_time = Math.round(end_time - start_time) / 1000;
    console.log("Time for one iteration: ", total_time);
  }
  const POLLING_INTERVAL = 1000;

  func();
  setInterval(func, POLLING_INTERVAL);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1); //Oder cl eine reconnection function??
});
```

The time for one iteration increases very fast. It starts like this:

```
Time for one iteration:  58.164
Time for one iteration:  73.696
Time for one iteration:  71.65
Time for one iteration:  87.609
Time for one iteration:  79.979
Time for one iteration:  81.445
Time for one iteration:  105.547
Time for one iteration:  102.197
Time for one iteration:  124.212
```

And after 15 minutes it is like this:

```
Time for one iteration:  861.125
Time for one iteration:  692.99
Time for one iteration:  880.155
Time for one iteration:  844.738
Time for one iteration:  839.594
Time for one iteration:  1019.032
```

Can someone tell me why this does happen? I understand, that it increases at the beginning because more iterations are running at the same time. Every one sec a new one starts and the first one needs 60 seconds, so I expect 60 running at the same time and the amount stays the same because one finishes and another one starts.
Why does it not work as I thought?

THANKS!

Comment: setInterval is not accurate and I am guessing there is something else going on in your code if it slows down after a time. You are logging the time for cacl to run so your issue is with the calc function. Hard to guess what could be the issue with the code provided.

Comment: You may want to look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: Since you have marked `main` as `async`, but it doesn't await anything and it doesn't return a promise, what are the conditions under which you intend `main` to resolve?

Comment: I think its because of the actual work being done in `calc(route)` itself.

Comment: Looks like your `calc` function is spending a lot of time executing JavaScript code, and is not really launching an asynchronous task. Or if it does, it only makes up a small part of what it does. By consequence the event queue fills up with timer events, as they don't really get to run before the JavaScript call stack is empty.

Comment: But I want to run a few calculations at the same time. I am fetching some prices and don't want to wait the 60 seconds until the first round finished. Is there a better opportunity to say like only 5 calculations at the same time or something like this?
And if I want to await the first one to finish, where do I have to set the await statement? I am awaiting the calc(route) already.

Comment: If your calculations are implemented as JavaScript code, then you cannot expect them to run at the same time. JavaScript runs as a single thread, whether you use `await` or not. If you want to have pre-emptive concurrency, then you need to increase the number of threads by using Web Workers. Look it up.

Comment: That would mean, I can also run one after another right? If I only can run one job at the same time. 
I am running a for loop, so calc(route) is called like 10 times, can I call the 10 routes at the same time to fetch data asynchronously? Because they do not have to run one after another.
And is there a function to run func() directly after the one before has finished (Cron also runs at a certain interval if I read correctly)?