# Node.js Promise.all analyze before all tasks are ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I do have a script which is fetching different price data:

```
async function main() {
  async function func() {
    const promises = routes.map((route) => calc(route, amount_start));
    const completedItems = await Promise.all(promises);
    completedItems.forEach(function (res) {
      if (res.result[5] > amount_start * 1) {
        console.log("Good Trade");
      }
    });
  }

  while (true) {
    await func();
  }
}
```

`routes` includes like 15 different `route`. So the code is running for approxemately 5 seconds, which is good. But now the code is waiting until all 15 route are finished. Is there a way to fetch the prices in parallel like its done already, but after that don't wait until all prices are fetched, but if one is fetched, analyze it with

```
if (res.result[5] > amount_start * 1) {
    console.log("Good Trade");
}
```

and do not wait for the other routes to finish?
I think I loose too much time by waiting for all routes to finish.

Thank you

Comment: Wow, you're asking a lot of questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815139/setinterval-iterations-runtime-increases) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901023/node-js-multithread-program) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916690/node-js-promise-all-javascript-heap-out-of-memory) about essentially the same code.  Perhaps you need to spend more time learning how these asynchronous concepts and promises work rather than just asking people to write all your code for you.

Comment: What's the point of `while(true) { await func(); }`?  That will be an infinite loop unless `func()` rejects.

Comment: I want to check the routes constantly

Answer (score 0):

If you want each route to be handled independently - just do so

```
const handleRoute = async (route) => {
    const res = await calc(route, amount_start);
    if (res.result[5] > amount_start * 1) {
        console.log("Good Trade");
    }
    handleRoute(route);
}
routes.forEach(handleRoute)
```

Comment: But with this code it seems like there the routes fetched one after another and not parallel, right?

Comment: nope ... each route is independently fetched over and over

Comment: Ok thanks. If I try, the 'calc' function is not executed. The routes are there. The 'route' and 'amount_start' are also correctly in the function, but calling the 'calc' function does not work. Can u tell me, why handleRoute(route) is called inside the handleRoutefunction?